# Extract two dictionary from one dictionary

Tags: python, django

I send post parameter like

```
css=request.POST['q']
css=css.encode('utf-8')
```

and css has content like

```
{
    "container": {
        "border-color": "white",
        "border-width": "0px",
        "height": "419px",
        "width": "200px",
        "border-style": "solid",
        "position": "relative",
        "background-color": "white"
    },
    "elemorder": {
        "productcode": {
            "font-size": "14px",
            "line-height": "18px",
            "color": "blue",
            "border-width": "0px",
            "letter-spacing": "0px",
            "text-decoration": "none",
            "height": "40px",
            "width": "200px",
            "border-color": "white",
            "font-weight": "normal",
            "font-style": "normal",
            "position": "absolute",
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "font-family": "Arial",
            "border-style": "solid",
            "display": "block",
            "background-color": "#3385D6",
            "text-align": "center"
        },
        "name": {
            "font-size": "14px",
            "line-height": "18px",
            "color": "blue",
            "border-width": "0px",
            "letter-spacing": "0px",
            "text-decoration": "none",
            "height": "40px",
            "width": "200px",
            "border-color": "white",
            "font-weight": "normal",
            "font-style": "normal",
            "position": "absolute",
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "font-family": "Arial",
            "border-style": "solid",
            "display": "block",
            "background-color": "#3385D6",
            "text-align": "center"
        },
        "url": {
            "font-size": "14px",
            "line-height": "18px",
            "color": "blue",
            "border-width": "0px",
            "letter-spacing": "0px",
            "text-decoration": "none",
            "height": "40px",
            "width": "200px",
            "border-color": "white",
            "font-weight": "normal",
            "font-style": "normal",
            "position": "absolute",
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "font-family": "Arial",
            "border-style": "solid",
            "display": "block",
            "background-color": "#3385D6",
            "text-align": "center"
        },
        "price": {
            "font-size": "14px",
            "line-height": "18px",
            "color": "blue",
            "border-width": "0px",
            "letter-spacing": "0px",
            "text-decoration": "none",
            "height": "40px",
            "width": "200px",
            "border-color": "white",
            "font-weight": "normal",
            "font-style": "normal",
            "position": "absolute",
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "font-family": "Arial",
            "border-style": "solid",
            "display": "block",
            "background-color": "#3385D6",
            "text-align": "center"
        },
        "id": {
            "font-size": "14px",
            "line-height": "18px",
            "color": "blue",
            "border-width": "0px",
            "letter-spacing": "0px",
            "text-decoration": "none",
            "height": "40px",
            "width": "200px",
            "border-color": "white",
            "font-weight": "normal",
            "font-style": "normal",
            "position": "absolute",
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "font-family": "Arial",
            "border-style": "solid",
            "display": "block",
            "background-color": "#3385D6",
            "text-align": "center"
        },
        "imgurl": {
            "font-size": "14px",
            "line-height": "18px",
            "color": "blue",
            "border-width": "0px",
            "letter-spacing": "0px",
            "text-decoration": "none",
            "height": "227",
            "width": 200,
            "border-color": "white",
            "font-weight": "normal",
            "font-style": "normal",
            "position": "absolute",
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "font-family": "Arial",
            "border-style": "solid",
            "display": "block",
            "background-color": "#3385D6",
            "text-align": "center",
            "left": 0,
            "top": 80
        },
        "desc": {
            "font-size": "13px",
            "line-height": "18px",
            "color": "blue",
            "border-width": "0px",
            "letter-spacing": "0px",
            "text-decoration": "none",
            "height": "69",
            "width": "200px",
            "border-color": "white",
            "font-weight": "normal",
            "font-style": "normal",
            "position": "absolute",
            "overflow": "auto",
            "font-family": "Arial",
            "border-style": "solid",
            "display": "block",
            "background-color": "#3385D6",
            "text-align": "center",
            "left": 0,
            "top": 307
        }
    }
}
```

and I put that in css variable. I am trying to put dictionary like

```
elemorder=css['elemorder']
container=css['container']
```

but I get error **string indices must be integers, not str** How to create two variable (dictionary) elemorder and container ?

Comment: why don't use 11.1. pickle — Python object serialization — Python v2.7.3 documentation -> http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html to serilze data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From POST request you get str not dict. Try to use json lib like

```
import json
css = json.loads(request.POST['q'])
```

Comment: I think you mean `json.loads(request.POST['q'])`

Comment: Yes, of course )) but I confusied what topic starter's framework get requests as strings, at pyramid for example it came as UnocodeMultiDict for example ))

Answer (score 2):

You need to serialize your data, pass it to Django app, and then deserialize.

JSON-serialization looks good for your task.